# Angular 2/4/6 show and hide divs independently

Tags: html, css, angular

I am fairly new to do things in Angular so I might overlook something:

I am generating a multiple div rows with *ngFor. Each of the row has a toggle button and a hidden sub-div (and the sub-divs can also have hidden sub-divs).

What I want to try and do is to show and hide the sub-divs independently when clicking on the toggle button (and also the toggle button icon should change). I managed to get it working either with opening all divs at the same time or when clicking on one row-toggle it will open the sub-div.

But when I click on another it will close the previous one that was clicked and open the currently clicked on one.
I was thinking about using an array but that would only work for the first layer of divs and not for the nested ones (since I don´t know how many, initially).

Here some illustration of opened sub- and sub-sub divs:

```
rows      rows
>AA       -AA
>BB         >aa
>CC   ->  >BB
>DD       -CC
>FF         -cc
               c
           >DD
           -FF
             >ff
```

Comment: Welcom to Stack Overflow. Can you share your code?

Comment: Please share a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using e.g. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="hero of heroes">
   {{ hero.name }}
   <button (click)="hero.show = !hero.show">show/hide</button>
   <div class="sub" *ngIf="hero.show">
      more info here
   </div>
</div>
```

Add some css to emphasize the sub section

Comment: OK, that did the trick, thanks a lot. I was using the index of the ngFor instead of the item itself (no idea why/how I ended up using it in the first place...)

Answer (score 0):

You need accordion 
try this:

You can make use of simple CSS and make it simple.

**HTML**

```
   <table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let game of games; let i = index" [ngClass]="{activetab: isActive(game.label)}">
            <div (click)="getSub(game.label);">
                <!-- use the uniqueId here  -->
                <td>{{game.date}}</td>
                <td>{{game.label}}</td>
                <td>{{game.score}}</td>
            </div>
            <table>
                <tbody [ngClass]="{activetab: isActive(game.label)}">
                    <tr *ngFor="let subgame of game.sub">
                        <td>{{subgame.date}}</td>
                        <td>{{subgame.label}}</td>
                        <td>{{subgame.score}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
tr .activetab {
    display: block !important;
}
```

**TS**

```
      isActive(id) {
        return this.selected === id;
      }

     getSub(id) {
   //TODO//
    this.selected = (this.selected === id ? null : id);
  }
```

I think this should work fine.